# How to display hierarchail json as tree in lwc

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a JSON object.

```json
[
  {
    "label": "Lauren Boyle",
    "name": "Lauren Boyle",
    "expanded": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Banoth Srikanth",
        "name": "Banoth Srikanth",
        "expanded": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "label": "Stella Pavlova",
            "name": "Stella Pavlova",
            "expanded": true,
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Srikanth",
        "name": "Srikanth",
        "expanded": true,
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to display this as a tree without using lightning-tree. How can I display this tree? I have tried multiple ways, but I am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show json data as a collapsible tree , i would suggest you to use  JavaScript libraries.
[Here's](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-json-viewer.html) list of some libraries to do that.